# how to download images from google using python

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup, automation, web-crawler

I want to downoad images from google results and automate the process too. How do I go about doing that? I wote this code but to no use. I found an empty directory. If I could use any other search engine, that would also be alright.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os


def download_images(query, num_images, save_folder):
    # Create the save_folder if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(save_folder):
        os.makedirs(save_folder)

    # Perform Google image search
    search_url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}&tbm=isch"
    response = requests.get(search_url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    # Parse the HTML response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Download and save the images
    image_count = 0
    for img in soup.find_all('img'):
        try:
            img_url = img['src']
            if img_url.startswith('http') and img_url.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif')):
                image_count += 1
                image_path = os.path.join(save_folder, f"{image_count}.jpg")
                with open(image_path, 'wb') as file:
                    response = requests.get(img_url)
                    response.raise_for_status()
                    file.write(response.content)
                print(f"Downloaded image {image_count}/{num_images}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error downloading image: {e}")

        if image_count == num_images:
            break


# Example usage
query = "cats"
num_images = 1000
save_folder = query.replace(' ', '_')
os.makedirs(save_folder, exist_ok=True)
download_images(query, num_images, save_folder)
```

I tried to use the beautiful soup to filter out images and download them to my system, but to no use. It just created an empty directory cats

Comment: Did you actually look at all the images that were returned? There does not seem to be any image such that `img_url.startswith('http') and img_url.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif'))` evaluates to `True`.